# Swift - how to use Core Bluetooth to receive values while the app is ON?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm creating an app and need to receive values from a peripheral device every few seconds.

However, I know how to implement the app with one view. I just do something like

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate
```

and then implement the methods.
 However, when I switch views, would I have to do everything over again?? How do I make it so that I receive bluetooth values when I'm on ANY screen on the app. For example, I switch from home page to a settings page, but I still want to receive values the entire time.

How do I make it so that I receive values when the app is both in the foreground and also the background?

Comment: You would normally implement the Bluetooth functions in some other class and hold an instance of that class on your AppDelegate.  This class can use NSNotifications to update the rest of the app when events occur

Comment: Would it work to just copy and paste the bluetooth methods in every view? It would be redundant but would it work

Comment: You can't have the methods in every view, as only one object can be the delegate at any point in time.  You could switch the delegate each time you moved to a new view controller but this would lead to lots of code duplication and makes things generally a whole lot harder.

Comment: gotcha - and I can check if an NSNotification happens on the view that I am on currently?

Comment: Yes, any object can use `NSNotificationCenter` to subscribe to notifications they are interested in

Comment: You could use a singleton that handle the bluetooth stuff and use NSNotification to alert objects that could be interested.